# how to make navigation drawer menu items center in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem, text-align

First of all I saw one stack thread regarding the same question but its not completely working for me may be because I am a newbie if anybody knows please help me , I am in navigation drawer now I want make the menu items to align in center [something just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXbz0.png)

this is what I got from stack overflow

```
  int positionOfMenuItem = 0; //or any other postion
  MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
  SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsItemTitle);

  s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

  item.setTitle(s);
```

I wrote this code in activity main and I am not sure that what is `settingsItemTitle`in this code so studio giving me error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'settingsItemTitle'

if anybody knows please help me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `MenuItem` (along with, I'm guessing, `NavigationView`), just use a vertical LinearLayout for your drawer content. You'll be able to style it any way you want.

Comment: It's supposed to be a CharSequence (or String) indicating the title of the item.

Comment: by default what it will be in android studio if it is a navigation drawer activity?

Comment: It's whatever title you give that MenuItem in XML. For instance, in the screenshot some of the settingsItemTitles are Profile, All Appointments, and Reports.

Comment: its not only one item by default only 6 menu items are there

Comment: That's why you're grabbing the position of the menuItem using positionOfMenuItem. You should really learn some Java before you attempt any of this:  https://www.udacity.com/course/java-programming-basics--ud282

Answer (score 0):

You can try developing a custom drawer where you can place the menu items in the centre.

[Custom navigation drawer](https:///www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

`settingsItemTitle` should be replaced by the title of your MenuItem.
In case the title was already set in the menu layout file, you could rewrite your code like:

```
 int positionOfMenuItem = 0; //or any other postion
 MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
 SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());

 s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

 item.setTitle(s);
```

This works, if you call it in the overwritten `onCreateOptionsMenu` method of your Activity, after having inflated the menu.

If you intend to do it for all items of your menu, you need to loop over them. Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
     MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
     SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());

     s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

     item.setTitle(s);
 }
```

I think setting this in an own layout, as Gavin pointed out in his answer, would be neater, but come at the price of not being able to use the Android off the shelf menu.